# Using push notifications when a user allows the notifications later in ios 11

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, swift4, ios11

I have set up an app that asks the user if they can receive local push notifications. It works fine if they allow it.  But if they don't allow it how do I save the notifications for when they turn it on in settings.

See I have a reminder app that sends reminders at a given time via a push notification.  It works fine if the app starts and they allow the notifications from the start.

But what happens if a user enters a reminder for say noon on Tuesday when the notifications aren't allowed. Then they go into settings to turn it on and come back to my app.  The notification was never created since they didn't allow them.

```
1. Can I create notifications when they aren't allowed but work if the user enables them?
2.Should I check if notifications are created everytime the app starts or hits the homepage?
```

I wonder what is best practice. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you will have to recreate your local notifications every time user changes his notification preferences. You can go ahead and schedule local notification as and when it makes sense for your app to do so. Like once user says he wants reminder on Tuesday, you create local notification for that n move on. Whether to show local notification or not, if shown how is it shown in form of alert, banner all will be decided by iOS based on user's notification settings.

Comment: Whenever the user tries to set and reminder.. first check whether the notification permission is allowed or not. if allowed set the notification if not, first prompt the user asking to allow the notification first.

Comment: Because iOS permission alerts are shown only once, as a work around we show custom alert first explaining why this permission is required, and once user says ok to it we show actual permission alert. Once we have permission, we dont bother about subsequent change in permission, you keep stacking up your local notifications and expect iOS to deal with it. Lots of tutorials asks you to accept permission in first shot and then they show code to add alert creating a illusion that you cant create one without permission, u can create one but it might not be shown :)